# Unity3D - Unexpected results from Vector3.Reflect

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 3D game. One feature I want is 'classic' bouncing projectiles where bullets etc richocet off of surfaces. The issue I'm having is that my code works fine on some surfaces but not others. I've recorded a 15 second video to illustrate:

[You tube vid](https://youtu.be/2rkPqFk_FYQ)

In the example the normals on the walls to the left are facing -Z and facing Z to the right. The walls are identical models and their normals are all correctly pointing outwards. You can see that the shot correctly bounces off one set of walls but not the other.

The code I'm currently using in OnCollision() is:

```
transform.LookAt(Vector3.Reflect(transform.position - startPosition, contact.normal.normalised));
```

Where the Vector3 startPosition is assigned when first firing the projectile and on each bounce. The rest of the code is simple stuff which would have no effect on this issue apart perhaps from in FixedUpdate where I do this to propel the projectile forward:

```
rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
```

I've tried the following which all give identical results:

```
Vector3 velocity = transform.forward;
velocity = 2 * (Vector3.Dot(velocity, Vector3.Normalize(contact.normal))) * Vector3.Normalize(contact.normal) - velocity; //Following the formula  v' = 2 * (v . n) * n - v
transform.LookAt(velocity);
```

---

```
transform.LookAt(Vector3.Reflect(rb.velocity, contact.normal));
```

---

```
transform.LookAt(Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, contact.normal) * transform.forward * -1);
```

I've also tried using the rigidbody but I'm not sure how to proceed there:

```
rigidbody.AddTorque(Vector3.Reflect(rigidbody.velocity, contact.normal.normalized),ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Any idea what could be going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: the video is private

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it's public now

Comment: Maybe it collides multiple times? Add Debug.Log() to OnCollision to see which directions it takes, and Debug.DrawRay() too. Could be also that lookat() doesnt get set before FixedUpdate runs again..

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it was a problem with LookAt not completing before FixedUpdate. Solution was to assign the Reflect to a Vec3 during the collision then in fixed update use that vector in the rb.AddForce like: target = Vector3.Reflect(transform.forward, contact.normal.normalized); ... rb.AddForce(target.normalized * projSpeed);

Comment: fixed update?  you should never be using it.  in any event, all of this can be done totally automatically (and about 100000x more efficiently) just using Unity's built-in physics

Comment: From the docs: 
In a script, the FixedUpdate function is recommended as the place to apply forces and change Rigidbody settings (as opposed to Update, which is used for most other frame update tasks). The reason for this is that physics updates are carried out in measured time steps that don't coincide with the frame update. FixedUpdate is called immediately before each physics update and so any changes made there will be processed directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just putting the answer in the right place to be used by people with the same problem.

*Solution* was to assign the Reflect to a Vector3 during the collision then in `FixedUpdate` use that vector in the `rb.AddForce` like:

`target = Vector3.Reflect(transform.forward, contact.normal.normalized);`

`rb.AddForce(target.normalized * projSpeed);`